# What is the result of a JS ES6 "yield array.map" with call saga effect?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux-saga

I have this piece of code:

```
function* sendArray (array, method) {

  yield array.map((element) => {
    return call(method, element)
  })
}
```

## If you don't know redux/saga

`call` is a synchronous function. `map` is an asynchronous one. If you `yield` and array of instructions, it will wait for the whole array to be executed.

**Question**: are the `call` instructions going to be executed in parallel, or are they going to wait for the previous one to be finished ?

## If you know redux/saga

Well, then you know what I mean. This function is a bit simplified and is part of one of my sagas, and `method` is a function that queries the API.

Are the `call` functions executed in parallel ?

Comment: What made you believe that `map` is an asynchronous function? I think you mixed up the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the `call` functions executed in parallel?

Not exactly, every `call` invocation is synchronous and `map` does execute sequentially. However, the asynchronous tasks started by all the `call`s will indeed run in parallel, and `yield`ing the array will wait for all results from them.

Comment: So first the array is mapped and returns an array of `call` instructions, and **then** the output array is yielded ?

Comment: I logged every call instruction with a timeout of 3 seconds. Indeed, they are all run in parallel.

Comment: It returns an array of whatever the things that `call(…)` returns are, yes, and then that is yielded. It could be promises or some saga-specific representation of the asynchronous task, I'm not sure.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you !